# While loop not working despite q+=1 at the end

Tags: python, while-loop

I want my code to loop through the values of mdelt to get ffa at the end, and plot mdelt vs ffa. The issue is is that when I run the code, it doesn't loop through the values of mdelt, and I just ffa as a list of the same value. I'm not sure why this is not working and how to fix it? I thought the q+=1 at the end should make sure it is looping properly.

```
i = 0

mdelt = np.arange(0, 160, 8)
ffa = []
fslow = []
q = 0

while q<len(mdelt):
    delta_0 = np.linspace(-180*10**6, -20*10**6, mdelt[q]) #red detuned laser - must be <0 to excite atom

    while i<len(delta_0):
        delta_p = delta_0[i] - (k*v_p) + (mu_eff*B)/hbar #laser beam propagating -k
        delta_n = delta_0[i] + (k*v_p) - (mu_eff*B)/hbar #laser beam propagation +k
        
        F = (hbar*k*L*s0)/2 * (1/(1+s0+(2*delta_p/L)**2) - 1/(1+s0+(2*delta_n/L)**2)) #scattering force
        accn = (F)/m_Rb #deceleration due to scattering force
        i +=1

    a = np.sum(accn) #sum of the acceleration's from each force exerted
    
    
    # Atom will only be stopped if final velocity is = 0 due to the scattering force
    D = 0.040 #m - diameter of the MOT beam
    v_cMOT = (-2*a*D)**0.5 #m/s^2 - capture velocity of the MOT - want final velocity to be 0
    
    v_cSLOW = (v_cMOT**2-2*a*z0)**0.5 #capture velocity of the slower
    
    # Flux of atoms captured in MOT
    
    fa, err = quad(Maxwell, 0, v_cMOT) #integrate MB distribution from 0 to capture velocity
    ffa.append(fa)
    q+=1
```

Comment: Do you not need to reset `i = 0` AFTER the inside while loop?

Comment: It looks like you could replace both while loops with a for loop. There is only once occurence each for `i += 1` and `q += 1`, and no if-else for those variables either. Using a for loop is likely to be much clearer and avoid the mistake of forgetting to reset a counter variable.

Answer (score 0):

delta_0 returns an empty array so the code doesn't make it to the second while loop.

Comment: To expand: `mdelt[q]` is 0 for the first iteration where `q == 0`, and `linspace(start, end, 0)` returns an empty array.